# How to order values on multiples columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I've trying to figure out how to order values on multiples columns but I cannot find an answer

Below is how the values are right now:

```
            A   B   C   D   E   F
Row(1)     20   1   3   5   2   4  
Row(2)     19  11  12  14  16   8
```

I would like to find a way to order them on the below way

```
            A   B   C   D   E   F
Row(1)      1   2   3   4   5   8
Row(2)     11  12  14  16  19  20
```

The above is just part of the huge table I have but I can only sort information by column or by row but not all the data

Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: What is the actual requirement, and why *must* it be done this way, rather than in a way that is natively supported (and intuitive) for spreadsheet users/consumers?

Comment: E.g., I can kind of see that the requirement is "Flatten the array and sort it ascending, but break it after every *n* (in this example: 6) columns, and wrap to the next row.

Comment: I'm working with frequency distribution tables and according with the information I've the values most be un order like on the 2nd example

Comment: OK, so there's no real relationship between rows/columns like in an ordinary table/matrix/etc.?

Comment: No , there is not . I do not have headers but the values must be in order. Is there a way to get the 1st, 2nd, 3rd lowest  values

Comment: Absolutely. Give me about 30 seconds to dump my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the `System.Collections.ArrayList` to flatten the two-dimensional range. The `ArrayList` object has a `.Sort` method (and also a `.Reverse` method, if you ever need that).

So, this approach captures the range, dumps it in to an `ArrayList`, sorts it (ascending) and then writes it back out to the original range:

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
Dim sel As Range

Dim arr As Variant, val As Variant
Dim lst As Object
Dim i As Long

'Simplistic case of capturing the range to operate against, modify if needed
Set sel = Application.InputBox("Please select the table (excluding headers) to sort", "Flatten & sort", Type:=8)
' Dump the range values in a 2-d array
arr = sel.Value

'Flatten the range/array in to the ArrayList object
Set lst = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each val In arr
    lst.Add val
Next

'Sort the ArrayList
lst.Sort
' If you ever need to reverse the list, you can do:
' lst.Reverse

' Dump the sorted ArrayList values back to the worksheet:
For i = 1 To lst.Count 
    sel(i) = lst.Item(i - 1) 
Next

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Youre the man! I've been reading about macros and I'm still learning but what you did was beautiful. I really appreciate you took the time to help me :) You are awsome!!!

Comment: The `ArrayList` object is not often used and you won't find easy reference to it, but it is there -- I learned about it here on StackOverflow :) and I figured this would be a good use for it that didn't involve creating temporary data sheet to sort the list (that's another way you could do it, but it would be less-elegant).

Comment: `arr = Selection.Value` needs to be changed to `arr = sel.Value` and there should be some error handling.  But good work +1

Comment: @ThomasInzina noted on the `sel` vs `Selection` (I had originally hardcoded to `Selection` before changing to `Application.InputBox` and forgot to update the next line.  I'll leave error-handling to OP :)

Comment: There is a simpler way to write the values back to the worksheet: `For i = 1 To lst.Count`
        `sel(i) = lst.Item(i - 1)`
    `Next`

Comment: Touché, @ThomasInzina -- updated with the simpler loop.